# Using Pandas to trim rows in a csv

Tags: pandas

In a table with a lot (thousands) of columns, I try to use Pandas to 'trim' the rows, this way:

From this:

```
A1 [...] B1 [...] C1 [...] D1 [...]  
A2 [...] B2 [...] C2 [...] D2 [...]  
...
```

To get this:

```
A1 [...]  
B1 [...]  
C1 [...]  
D1 [...]  
A2 [...]  
B2 [...]  
C2 [...]  
D2 [...]  
...
```

A, B, C... are 'checkpoints', where I want to trim the row.
[...] means a lot of columns.

In Pandas one could define a dictionary with all the columns in each fragment, but they are just too many. I've looked in the documentation checking for some option such as "Append columns from A to B", without success.

Comment: Can you update your post with few real lines, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to split rows. If this table is in a file, you can try:

```
import itertools
import re

ROW = re.compile(r'([A-Z][0-9])\s+([^\s]+)')

data = []
with open('table.txt') as fp:
    for row in fp.readlines():
        data.append(ROW.findall(row))

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data),
                  columns=['checkpoint', 'value'])
```

```
>>> df
  checkpoint  value
0         A1  [...]
1         B1  [...]
2         C1  [...]
3         D1  [...]
4         A2  [...]
5         B2  [...]
6         C2  [...]
7         D2  [...]
```